# Xcode for How to call function from one class to another class function in iPhone Apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4

JewelsSharedController.m:

```
-(void)GetCountries:(id)sender detailDictionary:(id)details
{
}
```

and I want to call this function in  `RootViewController`'s function like
RootController.m:

```
-(void)soapresult
{
    //i want to call ""GetContries "" here..
}
```

and i m call this `"soapresult"` in to

```
-(void)viewdidLoad
{
    [self soapresult];
}
```

but when calling function its crash

Comment: Please include crash logs or messages in questions where your code "crashes". The word alone is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

JewelsSharedController.h:

```
//...
-(void)GetCountries:(id)sender detailDictionary:(id)details;
//...
```

RootController.m:

```
#import "JewelsSharedController.h"

//...

-(void)soapresult
{
    JewelsSharedController * jewelsSharedController = [[JewelsSharedController alloc] init];
    [jewelsSharedController GetCountries:yourSender detailDictionary:yourDetails];
    [jewelsSharedController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
-(void)GetCountries:(id)sender detailDictionary:(id)details
```

{

}

To

```
+(void)GetCountries:(id)sender detailDictionary:(id)details
```

{

}

And then to call it in another class simply do

```
[JewelsSharedController GetCountries];
```

What we are doing is creating a class function, what that means is you can call the function directly on the class without having to initialize an instance of the class first.